# How to interpret this criterion of logistic regression result

Tags: logistic, hypothesis-testing, aic, likelihood-ratio

I run a backward variable selection logistic regression and find out the SAS program selected 12 variables and give me the output like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

It is funny that my configuration of the SAS backward selection is to make the SC(SBC) lower. Overall, the result looks like the SC result suppose that intercept with covariates is worse. But other two guys AIC and -2logL supports that Intercept with corvar is better model.

May you guys make some judge ment on this result and test output?

Comment: Have you checked out the answers to this question - http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3984/aic-and-sc-value?

Comment: @PeterEllis, I just checked. I am doing predicting model, so my model is good with those covariate....? And I　find a page interpreting that aic and sc are kind of "indicators" but checking the model with -2 log likelihood and degree of freedom improvement is better decision making.  http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/library/comp_repeated.htm

Comment: @Wenhao.SHE I would strongly suggest that you, as the human, select the variables that go into the model based on logic and theory.  The best a machine can do is data mine.  Stepwise selection methods are notorious for capitalizing on sample idiosyncrasies.  As for your fit statistics, have you considered looking at something like the area under the ROC curve (c-statistic)?  I find it's a much more intuitive measure of model fit.

Comment: @Will, I just post the ROC curve. May you have a look?> I try to predict whether tomorrow a forex pair is up or down. as you can see, the variable is frequecy of key trading related words. It makes sense for human, right? May you give more comments after viewing the roc?  Thanks

Comment: @Wenhao.SHE, I see.  There isn't any sort of theory here, this really is just data mining.  I would use the AIC in this situation.  As to the c-statistic, a value of .5 means your model's predictions are no better than chance while a value of 1 would mean perfect prediction.  It's just a nice intuitive way for humans to pick one model over another.  For your purposes it probably isn't as useful as the AIC.  This isn't my subject area but I would hope for a c stat higher than .75.

Comment: @Will Hi, My c score is 75% above, but I adjusted my model by following suggestion below now is 64% only. I guess it is good for you? Did you read the answer below. I think he really explained thing very well. Where you find reference to say c score is better to be .75 above? By the way, my prediction is binary 1 and 0 where 1 only have 15% and 0 has 85%. Does this distribution of binary target influence the c score?

Comment: More generally, I would also just remind you that often there are things that tend to coincide with each other for no apparent reason other than chance.  There's lots of examples (and mythology) in predictions about who or what party will win the U.S. Presidency.  I imagine a stepwise regression would be very quick to capitalize on these substantively meaningless 'predictors' which have been 100% accurate for 50 years or more but that in no way means they will be accurate in the next election cycle.

Comment: @Will, I know what you mean. but my predictor is from frequency of words on forex trading forum which is well organized and directly related to the eurusd pair of forex. That is all i can say and I thought it might be interesting to predict the direction of market based on the words trader using to describe market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the SC in conjunction with -2logL is suggesting that your model is overparametised.  That is, you can obtain a simpler model with less parameters but still a good fit to the data.  You will get a better SC if you set the slstay= option equal to the quantile of a chi-square with 1 degree of freedom at the difference between SC and -2LogL for the intercept only model.  For your output we have a difference of $447.224-440.919=6.305$ (from which I infer your sample size is $\exp(6.305)=547$).  Now we set the p-value equal to $Pr(\chi^2_1>6.305)=0.012$ (more generally set it to $Pr(\chi^2_1>\log(n))$.  This ensures that every model selection step will decrease the SC (approximately) without having to manually re-fit each model.  If you haven't specified the slentry= option then it defaults to $0.05$.  Thus my prediction is that you have some variables with p-values less than $0.05$ but greater than $0.012$.

Comment: I just updated my question with image showing that you are definitely right that I have some variable with p-value > 0.12. So, what is your suggestion? lower the stay from 0.05 to somewhere below 0.02? or even 0.01? I also post roc and lift graph. May you have a look. You are definitely a master of stat. Admiring...poor me

Comment: I read your comment again and I guess the right choice of stay should be 0.12 to lower the sc down to be consistent with -2loglikelihood result, right? I just tried and the sc just fall down below the 447.244. And the model is significanlly simplified now. SHould I say it is a good model now with roc and lift chart I added?

Comment: 0.012 not 0.12 you missed a decimal

Comment: Sorry for my careless.....Thanks again. It should be 0.012. Now the sc and -2 log shows same direction of indication. May I say it is a good modeling? I try to predict the up and down of a forex pair in next day by frequency of keywords on a forum of forex. The words left is the Intercept "problem" "game" and "direction".

Comment: @probabilityislogic, can I just ask (from someone who clearly knows more than I do) why does it matter if a simpler model could work just as well in this case?  If the goal is merely prediction and not understanding then problems like collinearity go away.  Who cares how we partial out the variance when all that matters is that the variance is partialled out.  I say this not to be be abrasive but because I assume there must be something I'm missing here.

Comment: Hallo, now my model is fine. I guess. I checked the c score again and found it like 0.64. @Will above mentioned that he prefer c score to be above 75%. My binary target has 15% 1 for up day and 85 percent for down day. Do you have any opinion on the c score and whether the distribution of c score influence the c score.

Comment: That c stat means your model makes the right prediction 64% of the time.  If that's acceptable is your judgement call.  To me that doesn't seem like it's worth much when I could be right almost as often (50% of the time) by just flipping a coin.

Comment: @Will, I would give you more details about my model. You are right, that the 64 is not high. But my model is to predict whether the Forex pair eurusd would go up AT LEAST 1% tomorrow as "1" in binary and other condition as "0" like flat or down of eurusd. Event 64% is not high, it is possible to build strategy based on the PREDICTED PROBABILITY as SCORE on each trading day. Then I could pick up highest day with, for example, 20% top high, to trade. Event it may be not 1%, but I do not loss in trading if it is "0" as flat market. By the way, 1% is kind of good up day in forex market.

Comment: @Will, continued on last comment. So, my basic idea is to build a SIMPLE and CONSISTENT MODEL to score the trading day by the predicted probability. Higher probability means high possibility for that day to be close to a "1%" day, even it is not a "1%" day, it is usually a good 0%-1% day which do not hurt my account. THAT IS WHY I set "1%" as kind of threshold but not the classic 0% to decide the typical up or down day. I hope it shifts the predicated probability to kind of bias of "1%" as good day. How do you think?

Comment: @Wenhao.SHE, there are lots of guides each suggesting what a good c stat is.  I'm not going to link to them because it's a substantive question.  Your response illustrates this perfectly.  It depends on your subject, model, and goal.  If you're ok with .64 then that's fine.  Really I guess anything above .5 is 'fine' if you're fine with it.  'Better' as defined by some fit stat is an arbitrary definition.  If the fit stat quantifies some dimension of the model you really care about then use it, but match that with some logic and common sense.  I'm off to bed.

Comment: @Will Thanks lot. I may use AIC and -2log to interpret my model and forgetting about sc if the trading result is good. Thanks lot. good dream

Comment: @will with regards to the simpler model, bic/sc properly takes account of the uncertainty in the model for the case of what you might call "speculative" modelling.  Also bic is equivalent (approximately) to a type of cross validation where you predict first obs with no data, the predict second obs using first data point, then third obs with first two, and so on.  the order that observations are used doesnt matter (even though it appears nonsymmetrical).  Compared to aic which is loo cv shows why bic is more stringent.  Both predict all obs once, but bic takes account of the learning process

Comment: Just last question. Should I really lower the stay option from 0.05 to 0.12 because the bic is the only criterion higher(slightly higher)?Because the lower stay option really made the c score from 75% to 64%. Is there a rule like we should always get consistency between -2log and bic? Thanks lot

Comment: I think what BIC is really telling you is that you have quite a bit of models which are "close" - i.e. you have a large amount of model uncertainty.  This can be seen because there are a fair amount of chi-square statistics of between $4$ and $6$.  You would see that if you plotted the SC for each model in the backwards selection process it would tend to drop steeply at first, and then flat for the last few steps.  Hence If your goal is prediction, then a model average may be a better way to go, using $\exp(-\frac{1}{2}SC)$ as the model weight.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I understand what you said about the "plotting the sc for each model and it would tend to drop steeply then flat". I just really can not find reference for "using exp(-1/2SC) as the model weight". How could I implement it? Is this "exp(-1/2SC)" like some kind of score or weights for model on each step? for example, I have 457.048 here as SC, so the score of my mode is exp(-1/2*457.048)? I think you are telling me that I should use BIC(SC) and really make it lower than the intercept only model, right?:) Thanks again

Comment: [Here]([http://www2.research.att.com/~volinsky/bma.html]) is a website which discusses Bayesian model averaging.  It also has an R package to implement it for logistic regression.  Contains lots of papers as well